# Richeditor Onlyoffice edit & save document

Tags: javascript, richedit, onlyoffice

I need to load MSWord file into embedded editor (onlyoffice), modify it, then upload to my server as MSWord file. 
I've already installed onlyoffice on my PC.
https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/demopreview#text

When i run JavascriptExample and press edit there is no editing allowed, how to enable document edit?
Is it possible to upload modified file (after pressing save) to my web server's url by http?
May be there is another solutions without using OnlyOffice.

Comment: There is other library like [Ajax WebDAV Library](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/opening_ms_office_docs), which provides API to edit and save MSWord document.

Answer (score 2):

The edit feature will not work unless you follow their procedure :

1. Download Document Server installation and set it up on your local server from **[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/teamlab/files/ONLYOFFICE%207.7/ONLYOFFICE-OnlineEditors-v2.5.7.exe/download)**
2. Select the programming language and download the code for the sample of online editors integration into your web site ( in your case **[javascript sample](https://api.onlyoffice.com/app_data/JavaScript%20Example.zip)** )
3. Edit the configuration files in the sample changing the default path for the one to the editors installed at step 1 , to do so :

   - Open **OnlineEditorsExampleJS.html** file in your example folder.
   - In #10 line `<script id="scriptApi" type="text/javascript" src="https://doc.teamlab.com/OfficeWeb/apps/api/documents/api.js"></script>` change te script path to your installed editor ( which you have downloaded in step 1 ).

**However**

There are so many good editors out there that in my opinion are much better than this one .

**Free Online Editors :**

1. **[Google Docs](http://www.google.com/docs/about/)**
2. **[Box](https://developers.box.com/)**

and if you dont mind using MS service itself , you can get started **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905340.aspx)**

Note :

This **[Library](http://blog.innovatejs.com/?p=184)** sounds promising , but it really lacks documentation , but i would rather bookmark it for future purposes.

Comment: i can't use services - files must be stored in server and server is inside VPN. Problem of onlyoffice - changed files saves to installed server, not my custom server (JBoss)

Comment: @DidarBurmaganov i dont undrstand , please clarify the services problem , and clarify the onlyoffice issue , did you follow procedure , and it worked , but you cant save files on custm server ?

Comment: i can not use google docs or similar services where user uploads files.
i am developing document flow system where users need to create/modify documents inside browser. OnlyOffice provides richeditor but it uploads madified doc to installed onlyoffice. I need richeditor with ability to transform to MS office file.

Comment: @DidarBurmaganov there is also a workaround for onlyoffice to fetch the generated file via php to your custom server.

Comment: if it possible to fetch via php then there should be java solution also. So at first i haven't seen such demo, but after your comment i found example on onlyoffice site (how could i miss it) :) so tomorrow i'll try it and if it works my problem would be solved ! i'll leave info about results before bounty expires :)

Comment: could you send your php example with installed locally onlyoffice distr, when i run java example it gives me exceptions about file not found so i want to see if i missed some configs, this would help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @DidarBurmaganov for sure but i need further details about your server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73672/discussion-between-didar-burmaganov-and-prollygeek).